# When running a compiled GCC file in the terminal

Tags: c, linux, terminal, shared-memory, memory-segmentation

P1 and P2 two processes that share a memory segment representing an integer N and
running in parallel.
the results is supposed to look something like :
process 1 :  2 4 6 8 10
27 29 31 33 35
52 54 56 58 60..
process 2 : 13 16 19 22 25
38 41 44 47 50
63 66 69 72 75

first process :

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>

#define cle 160

typedef struct mp{
 int pid;
 int pid1;
 int n;
}mp;
void handler(){}
main(){
 mp *m;
 int shmid;
 printf("yo");
 signal(SIGUSR1,handler);
 
 shmid = shmget(cle,sizeof(mp), IPC_CREAT|0666);
 m =(mp*)shmat(shmid,0,0);
 m->pid = getpid();
 m->n=0;
 printf("premier process  : ");
 while(m->n<100){
 
 do{
 m->n = m->n + 2;
 printf(" %d, ", m->n);
 }while(m->n%5 != 0 );
 kill(m->pid1,SIGUSR1);
  pause();
  printf("\n");
 }
 shmdt(m);

 
}
```

second process

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#define cle 130
typedef struct mp{
int pid;
int pid1;
int n;
}mp;

void handler (){};
int main(){
int shmid;
mp *m;
signal(SIGUSR1, handler);
shmid = shmget(cle,sizeof(mp), IPC_CREAT|0666);

m =(mp*)shmat(shmid,0,0);
m->pid1 = getpid();
pause();
printf("dexiéme process");
while(m->n<100){
do {
   m->n = m->n +3;
   printf(" %d, ",m->n);
}while(m->n %5 != 0);
kill(m->pid, handler);
pause();
}
}
```

I can't figure out why nothing happens when I run ./p1 and ./p2

Comment: Please indent/format your code like the samples in your learning material. And some blank lines here and there also help for readability.

Comment: I don't see any synchronization of the accesses to the shared memory.  The resulting behavior is undefined.  You should establish a process-shared mutex or semaphore with which each process can lock the shared memory for its exclusive use while it reads or updates it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger but doesn't the signal handler synchronize the processes, the first process pause after printing the first 5 numbers then the second process wakes up print the 5 numbers send the signal to the first process then pause and so on?

Comment: It is not for timing that you need to synchronize. It is for well-definedness of your (shared) memory accesses.  And for that, no, the signaling does not suffice.

Comment: That may not be the only issue with the code presented, but it's certainly one issue.

Comment: Note that `printf` is line buffered, so you won't see the output until you print a newline character, or call `fflush(stdout)`. So your output (or lack of output) will be confusing unless you end all of your `printf`s with `\n`.

Comment: You also need to run `./p2` first. Otherwise, this has no chance of working.

Comment: Shouldn't you use the same `cle` for them to use the same shared memory segment?